# Excel becomes unresponsive while it gets all the issues from JIRA using API using pagination

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, jira-rest-api

```vb
Sub Jira_for_all_issues_v6()
    Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, url As String, response As String, json As Object, startAt As Integer, batchSize As Integer, totalIssues As Integer, _
     issuesCount As Integer, has_subtsk As Boolean, print_row As Long, data As Object, ok_yes As Object, totalIssues5 As Integer, last_row_print As Long, _
     http1 As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, url1 As String, response1 As String, json1 As Object, user_name_password_in_base64_encoding As String, i As Integer
    Dim issues As Collection, StartTime As Double, SecondsElapsed As Double
StartTime = Timer
    user_name_password_in_base64_encoding = UserPassBase64()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Issue id"
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 2).Value = "Issue key"
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 3).Value = "Status"
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 4).Value = "priority"
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 5).Value = "reporter"
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 6).Value = "reporter Id"
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 7).Value = "creator"
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 8).Value = "creator"
        
        url1 = "https://jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=project AND issuetype in (Bug)&maxResults=" & 1 & "&startAt=" & 0
    
    'Set the HTTP request properties
    With http1
    .Open "GET", url1, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & user_name_password_in_base64_encoding
 
    
    'Send the HTTP request and retrieve the response
    .send
    End With
    response1 = http1.responseText
    
    'Parse the JSON data using a JSON parser library
    Set json1 = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response1)
    
    totalIssues = json1("total")
    
    startAt = 0
    batchSize = 100
'    print_row = 2
     Set ok_yes = json1("issues")
    
    Do While startAt < totalIssues
        'Set the URL to the JIRA REST API endpoint with the startAt and maxResults parameters
        url = "https://jira-/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=project AND issuetype in (Bug)&maxResults=" & batchSize & "&startAt=" & startAt
        
        'Set the HTTP request properties
        http.Open "GET", url, False
        
      
        http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        http.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & user_name_password_in_base64_encoding
        'Send the HTTP request and retrieve the response
        http.send
        response = http.responseText
        
        'Parse the JSON data using a JSON parser library
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
        
        'Extract the desired data from the parsed JSON data and insert it into your Excel worksheet
        
        issuesCount = json("issues").Count
        totalIssues5 = json("total")
        last_row_print = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        
        Set issues = json("issues")
        
        For i = 1 To issuesCount
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(last_row_print, 1).Value = issues(i)("id")
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(last_row_print, 2).Value = issues(i)("key")
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(last_row_print, 3).Value = issues(i)("fields")("status")("name")
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(last_row_print, 4).Value = issues(i)("fields")("priority")("name")
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(last_row_print, 5).Value = issues(i)("fields")("reporter")("displayName")
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(last_row_print, 6).Value = issues(i)("fields")("reporter")("name")
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(last_row_print, 7).Value = issues(i)("fields")("creator")("name")
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(last_row_print, 8).Value = issues(i)("fields")("creator")("displayName")
            
            last_row_print = last_row_print + 1
        Next i
        
        'Update the startAt parameter for the next batch of search results
        startAt = startAt + batchSize
    Loop
      SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

    MsgBox "All issues have been retrieved."
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```

There are about 1000 issues and it takes about 16 mins to run. While this runs the Excel app becomes unresponsive. How can prevent this and also any tips on how to optimize this code?

I tried turning off the `appliction.screenupdating` and it brought it down from 18 mins to 16 mins. Also I had increased the batch size from 50 to 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squeeze in a DoEvents somewhere in the loop, like this

```
...
    startAt = startAt + batchSize
    DoEvents
Loop
...
```

Comment: okay does it need to be at the starting of the loop or at the end and also how does it help in my case?

Comment: @AniruddhHS, While your macro runs, a backlog of events builds up. Without DoEvents, this backlog isn't handled. This is the unresponsiveness you have observed. DoEvents will pause the macro to handle this queue. Start or end of loop doesn't matter that much, as long as the queue doesn't build up.

Comment: hi, there's another issues with my code. when i run the same code, the time it takes to execute is different from time to time, the same batch size i am retrieving but each time the time varies from one execution to another execution. why is it like that???

Comment: Hard to tell. Put `Debug.Print "Before XXX" & Now()` and `Debug.Print "After XXX" & Now()` before and after various statements and inspect the debug output (Ctrl-G).